# Is it possible to make a local notification not appear in the history if the app is in the foreground?

Tags: ios

I thought with local notifications that they would only appear in the notification center history if the app wasn't running at the time of their expiry.
However this isn't what I'm observing, so I must have been mistaken.

Is it possible to schedule a local notification and if it expires while my app is currently in the foreground for the notification not to appear in the notification history?

Note that I cannot clear the notification history because it may contain push notifications my app received that I do not want deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try canceling the notification in your app delegate's didReceiveLocalNotification method if the application is active:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}
```